# What does the date exclusion for i-693 cover?

Tags: usa, immigration, uscis

In the documentation for [I-693, Report of Medical Examination and Vaccination Record](https://www.uscis.gov/i-693) it says,

> From Dec. 9, 2021, until Sept. 30, 2022, we are temporarily waiving the requirement that the civil surgeon’s signature be dated no more than 60 days before you file Form I-485.

What does that mean:

1. Form I-485's filed from Dec. 9, 2021, until Sept. 30, 2022.
2. Form I-485's processed from Dec. 9, 2021, until Sept. 30, 2022.
3. Civil surgeon signatures on I-693s made from Dec. 9, 2021, until Sept. 30, 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we are temporarily waiving the requirement that the civil surgeon’s signature be dated no more than 60 days before you **file** Form I-485.

Highlighted it for you. They're referring to the date of filing the form.

Usually you need to do the doctor's examination within 60 days before filing the AOS, but due to the pandemic they're easing this restriction. IIRC the doctor's examination results are valid for 2 years, that hasn't changed. From the same notice:

> It is still in the best interest of applicants to undergo the immigration medical examination close to the time of filing their Form I-485, as their Form I-693 only retains its evidentiary value for two years from the date of the civil surgeon’s signature. After the two-year timeframe, the applicant would need to submit a new Form I-693 if we have not adjudicated their Form I-485. This temporary waiver is effective until Sept. 30, 2022.

Comment: I'm guessing the file date is the date mailed. So I'll try to sum it up: normally you can bring it to them in person to the interview, but if I do that and the interview is scheduled more than 60 days after the health inspection it's not good. However, right now it is good. But because this rule suspension is soon to expire if my interview is after Sept. 30, 2022 it's not good again. Unless I mailed it in to them on or before Sept 30, 2022?

Comment: I don't know the answer here, but I question your assumption that the date of form filing would be the date of mailing. While some documents (for example, an IRS Form 1040 income tax return) are deemed "filed" on the mailing date, many (or most) other official forms are deemed "filed" only upon actual physical receipt (and perhaps official stamping) at the receiving government office.

Comment: @EvanCarroll the date of filing is the date on the receipt notice (receipt date). The 60 days suspension announcement said nothing about the interview.